# Using princexml and PDFreactor in Lightning component with version 43.0

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I want to know if Salesforce allows [princexml](https://www.princexml.com/) or [PDFreactor](https://www.pdfreactor.com/) js library to work if locker service is enabled. This files are used to convert html to PDF

Comment: Unless you are lucky and someone else has tried these, the quickest approach would be to try them yourself.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I have already spent lot of time with jsPDF library, hence I am looking for information beforehand.Is there list of JS library files available somewhere that is approved by salesforce.

Comment: AFAIK there is no list except this very old (and short) one [LockerService and Lightning Container Component: Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html). Salesforce are pretty quiet about this painful problem.

Comment: Here is an example of them aiming for more compatibility [Changes in Locker Service](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_lc_locker_service.htm), but libraries that walk all over the DOM are always going to be problematic.

Comment: To add to the comments of others, if possible, check to see if the libraries use `Strict` compatibility. If they do not, they will not be compatible with the Locker Service.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use the [DocRaptor][https://docraptor.com] service instead which is based on Prince. Disclosure: I am a DocRaptor developer. We're considering a Salesforce integration and feedback would be welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer on princexml and PDFReactor. I looked at the links you provided. Both of these run server side and as such, since Lightning runs client side, its not likely to be a suitable solution for creating PDFs from Lightning Components.

You would need to be able to make web services calls to a server you were hosting in order to use it. Unless you plan to host one of these on your own servers, they will not provide the kind of functionality to render PDFs from within a component.

With that having been said, you can get a free personal license of PDFReactor to run on your own personal machine (Windows, Mac, etc) which would make it worth investigating. Since it runs locally, from what I can see, it shouldn't be dependent on any JS in your component, but I'd expect it might have difficulties with some of the Lightning CSS. That's what you'd likely need to focus your testing on.

The greatest difficulty will be configuring the web services callouts to get it to print from your machine; something you might be able to do using localhost. Further, be aware that if you try to do anything with visualforce and Princexml, visualforce does not support xml.

I'll leave the rest to you.